# Do the artifact blasts hurt the final boss in the last mission in Wings of Liberty?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm still trying to complete it, and I'm not sure about this thing - when I activate the artifact, does it hurt Kerrigen?

Comment: @Kyralessa - you're correct. Can you come up with an alternate title that is still meaningful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It definitely hurts her, but doesn't kill her (if she has full HP). I believe that the artifact does 800 dmg to anything in its radius. If I recall correctly, Kerrigan has 2500 HP.

Comment: I believe it's 1000 damage in total. But otherwise, you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

The main use of the artifact in this mission is to clear the area around your base of enemy forces. Even if Kerrigan survives the blast, your own troops will make short work of her since there'll be nothing else to shoot at.

Comment: She can certainly survive the blast: I tried to blast her once and she was still there. I can't say whether or not she took damage from it though.